# Integrating Chatbot with Chatbase

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, chatbot, chatbase

How to Integrate my chatbot with google chatbase and that also using aws lambda function. This particular lambda function has my chatbot's backend written in node.js. So I would like to include chatbase along with it and i wonder how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to install the Chatbase NPM module:

`npm install --save @google/chatbase`

Which will install the module in your current project directory and modify your `package.json` to list it as a dependency to your project.

Once you [upload this app to AWS lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html) the library should continue to work.